# Eclipse Scala Worksheet error value is not a member of object

Tags: eclipse, scala, scala-ide

I have a simple class calc that squares and cubes the input:

```
object calc2 {

  def square(nmr: Int) = {
    calc.square(nmr)
  }

  def cube(nmr: Int) = {
    calc.cube(nmr)
  }

  def square(nmr: Double) = {
    calc.square(nmr)
  }

  def cube(nmr: Double) = {
    calc.cube(nmr)
  }
}
```

And I'm using a Scala Worksheet in Eclipse with calls to this object:

```
object test {
  calc2.square(3)                                 //> res0: <error> = 9.0
  calc2.cube(3)                                   //> res1: <error> = 27.0
  calc2.square(3.0)                               //> res2: <error> = 9.0
  calc2.cube(3.0)                                 //> res3: <error> = 27.0
}
```

However I get a error in the Editor for every line which says

> value square is not a member of object exercises2.calc2

[image]

As you can see the worksheet seems to do the calculation. So why am I getting this error?

Comment: I get the same error on the Scala worksheet of IntelliJ IDEA, probably it's a RELP thing.

Answer (score 0):

The below solution works for the same problem in IntelliJ IDEA, but I reckon something similar can be set in Eclipse as well.

The reason why the worksheet doesn't recognise your totally existing members is because they have been written (or re-written) after the last compilation. You can force the worksheet to *make the project* before run, thus making all the newly written or modified parts of your code visible to the underlying REPL. Credit goes to [this comment poster](https://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2012/12/04/scala-worksheet/#comment-60365).
In IntelliJ IDEA you set it as below, clicking on the wrench icon on your worksheet header:

[image]